# Как открыть ссылку в стандартном браузере без выбора в каком браузере открывать?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, если открываю ссылку через `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urri));`, то спрашивает, через какой браузер открывать.

Как избавиться от этого? Во многих приложениях при клике на ссылку/рекламу открывается страница в стандартном браузере, без запроса.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос, только на английском http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome

Comment: @Leonid там речь идет про гугл хром, а не стандартный браузер :)

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под стандартным? На разных устройствах могут быть установлены разные браузеры и не один. Пользователь может сам указать в настройках какой браузер использовать по умолчанию и тогда не будет появляться запроса с выбором.

Comment: @Leonid в том то и дело, что будет. У меня в настройках телефона установлен браузер по-умолчанию - UC, если я открываю рекламу и ссылки в большинстве приложений, они открываются в UC браузере. А в моем приложении у меня спрашивает, каким браузером мне воспользоваться. По ссылке которую прислали вы речь идет про Chrome, никак не про браузер выбранный пользователем по умолчанию.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, открыть ссылку в стандартном браузере можно так: 

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);